# 'wine: /home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends is not owned by you'

Tags: command-line, wine, games, users, playonlinux

Here's my problem :

I've been trying to install league of legends following this guide :
https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2004999 (It's in french, since I am french).

In this tutorial there is a moment when I'm asked to put this command in the terminal:

```
sudo WINEPREFIX=/home/$VOTRE_NOM/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/ winetricks -q vcrun2005 vcrun2013 vcrun2015
```

I should have been replacing the "$VOTRE_NOM" by my username wich is pop

Then I tried again but when typing :

```
sudo WINEPREFIX=/home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/ winetricks -q vcrun2005 vcrun2013 vcrun2015
```

*The real command I should've been typing in the first place.*

It gives me this output as an error:

```
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message 'wine: /home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends is not owned by you'
```

As asked here is the output for the same command line but without the `sudo`:

```
$ WINEPREFIX=/home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/ winetricks -q vcrun2005 vcrun2013 vcrun2015

Executing w_do_call vcrun2005
Executing load_vcrun2005 
Using native,builtin override for following DLLs: 
atl80 msvcm80 msvcp80 msvcr80 vcomp 
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_vcrun2005\override-dll.reg 
Executing wine vcredist_x86.EXE /q fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("C:\\users\\pop\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\", 00000000): stub 
fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x2002c/8200003 wait timed out 
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented. 
Executing w_do_call vcrun2013 Executing load_vcrun2013 
Using native,builtin override for following DLLs: 
atl120 msvcp120 msvcr120 vcomp120 
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_vcrun2013\override-dll.reg
------------------------------------------------------
Working around wine bug 17273 -- Manually extracting dlls
------------------------------------------------------
Executing cabextract -q --directory=/home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013 vcredist_x86.exe Executing cabextract -q
--directory=/home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013 /home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013/a2 /home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013/a2: WARNING; possible 16128 extra bytes at end of file. Executing cabextract -q
--directory=/home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013 /home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013/a3 /home/pop/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends//dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_vcrun2013/a3: WARNING; possible 16128 extra bytes at end of file. Unknown arg vcrun2015 Usage: /usr/bin/winetricks [options] [command|verb|path-to-verb] ... Executes given verbs.  Each verb installs an application or changes a setting.

Options:
    --force           Don't check whether packages were already installed
    --gui             Show gui diagnostics even when driven by commandline
-k, --keep_isos       Cache isos (allows later installation without disc)
    --no-clean        Don't delete temp directories (useful during debugging)
    --no-isolate      Don't install each app or game in its own bottle
-q, --unattended      Don't ask any questions, just install automatically
-r, --ddrescue        Retry hard when caching scratched discs
    --showbroken      Even show verbs that are currently broken in wine
    --verify          Run (automated) GUI tests for verbs, if available
-v, --verbose         Echo all commands as they are executed
-h, --help            Display this message and exit
-V, --version         Display version and exit

Commands:
(…)
WINEPREFIX=/home/pop/.local/share/wineprefixes/foobar
```

Comment: Did you try running it without `sudo`? Please [edit] and add the output of that.

Comment: Alright mate it's done!